# How to find Bilinears of a theory?

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, tensor-calculus, dirac-equation, klein-gordon-equation

I'm trying to understand how one finds the bilinears of a given theory. In most litterature the bilinears are not really derived but rather taken as fundamental.

The dirac bilinears are of course:
$$\bar{\Psi}\Psi, \;\; \bar{\Psi}\gamma^5\Psi, \;\;\bar{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}\Psi,\;\; \bar{\Psi}\gamma^5\gamma^{\mu}\Psi \;\; \text{and} \;\; \bar{\Psi}\sigma^{\mu\nu}\Psi.$$
My questions are:

- How does one find these to be the bilinears of the Dirac equation?
- Are there corresponding bilinears of the Klein-Gordon equation? (How do you find those?)

Comment: A bilinear is by definition a matrix sandwiched between the fields, and those matrices form a basis.

Comment: So because the dirac spinors have 4 components, the bilinears will simply be 16 matrices that span all 4x4 matrices?

Comment: Bu then, couldnt i choose just the 26 matrices with just 1 one and 15 zeros and use thise as bilinears?

Comment: You could, but it wouldn't be useful. The point of the five Dirac bilinears listed above is that they each transform differently (scalar, pseudoscalar, etc.) under Lorentz transformations.

Comment: As a analogous question, you might ask what basis to use for the spin states of two spin $1/2$ particles. It's useful to separate the states by how they transform under rotations, giving you the spin 1 triplet and the spin 0 singlet.

Comment: Bilinears for Dirac filed, differently from the field, itself are *observables* and they are the most elementary observables one can construct out of Dirac fields...

Comment: For a *charged* scalar KG field there are more elementary observables: $\phi(x) + \phi^*(x)$ and $i(\phi(x) - \phi^*(x))$. Corresponding objects for Dirac field would however violate causality, i.e., commutation relations...